# How to adapt a calculator application height written in html5 / javascript / css3 (which is inside an android webview) to any device screen height?

Tags: javascript, java, android, html, css

I'm using relative units for everything (percentages): fonts, width and height of a table, etc. But still the table which contains the calculator buttons and display, doesn't match any device's screen size.

I have tried setting every button's "height" attribute to a certain percentage, as well as the calculator's display, so that I could make the calculator box fit the entire device screen.

```
.botonesOP{

border-style:groove;
border-width:2px;
border-radius:10%;
text-align:center;
font-size:100%;
width:22.5%;
height:25%;



box-shadow: 7px 7px 30px rgb(113, 247, 135);
    background: radial-gradient(rgb(12, 133, 42), rgb(13, 68, 5), 
rgb(6, 44, 2));
    color: white;

}
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="operaciones.js"></script>
    <link href="estiloscalc.css" rel="stylesheet"/>



</head>

<body>



    <section>



        <div>


       <input type="text" id="display" readonly>

        </div>


                <input type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="siete()" value="7">
                <button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="ocho()">8</button>



                <button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="nueve()">9</button>

                <button type="button" class="botonesOP" onclick="mas()">+</button>






                <button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="cuatro()">4</button>
                <button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="cinco()">5</button>

                <button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="seis()">6</button>

                <button type="button" class="botonesOP" onclick="menos()">-</button>





                <td><button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="uno()">1</button>
                <td><button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="dos()">2</button>

                <td><button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="tres()">3</button>

                <td><button type="button" class="botonesOP" onclick="multip()">x</button>






                <button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="punto()">.</button>
                <button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="cero()">0</button>

                <button type="button" class="botonesN" onclick="igual()">=</button>

                <button type="button" class="botonesOP" onclick="divis()">/</button>






                <button type="button" class="botonesOP" onclick="ce()">C</button>
                <button type="button" id="botonEspecial" onclick="cuo()">CÚO</button>


    </section>






</body>






</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO @Alberto. Please could you share the HTML from your view so we can help.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike! Ok, I will share the HTML right away. Only I put the whole thing outside the table to check if it would work, without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is because your buttons height percentages are relative to their parent's height. 
In this case, the parent of your buttons is the `section` tag. This tag default height is just the minimal height for which all components fits in and not the screen's height. See more about the default height and it's behaviour [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp).

What you want to do is to give the `section` tag the same height as the screen. Than the buttons will be 25% of this `section` tag's height and thus 25% of the screen height. To do so, you'll need to give the `section` tag a height of 100%. But again, the `section` tag parent's height (`body`) has also a default height of the minimum needed. So you need to set the `body`'s height also to 100%. And the same for the `html` tag.

So all you need to add is this piece of css:

```
html, body, section {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much!!! It worked well, exactly what I needed! Thank you once again! :-)

Comment: @Alberto, you're welcome. Don't forget to vote up for the right answer and mark is as 'accepted'. It'll help others as well ;)